# How do I define a button element's onclick attribute using just JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

As it says in the title, I'm trying to create a button element in JavaScript, but when I try to set its `onclick` attribute, it just ignores it. I've looked at other questions with this topic on this site (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849683/define-function-in-javascript-onbuttonclick)), but everyone answers to put it in with HTML, like so:

```
<button id="buttonid" onclick="click(this);">
```

But my program dynamically creates the HTML buttons entirely with JavaScript (they're aligned on a table, so using a for loop is very useful. Plus I'm more familiar with JavaScript). Like this:

```
var b = document.createElement("button");
b.id = "buttonid";
b.onClick = "click(this);"; //I've tried many variations with no success
document.appendChild(b);
```

The button element is never declared in the HTML. I need a way to add the `onclick` attribute using JavaScript alone. I'm not very experienced with JQuery, so I would prefer just JavaScript.

Thank you in advance.

PS, I've tried all the following methods with both lowercase `.onclick` and camelcase `.onClick`:

```
b.onClick = "click(this);"; //just simply doesn't work
b.onClick = click(this);    //actually runs the program there, with some ambiguous "this" object
b.onClick = click;          //passes the actual function, but disallows the ability to pass the button's object (via "this")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you assign a JavaScript 'onclick' attribute dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007336/how-do-you-assign-a-javascript-onclick-attribute-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add the listener to the button and [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to pass the button as `this` for the handler function.

```
b.addEventListener(`click`, click.bind(b));
```

Or if you want to use `onClick`, just use `bind`:

```
b.onClick = click.bind(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
    var b = document.createElement("button");
    b.onClick = function(){
      alert("on click handler");
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try b.onClick = function(){ console.log("test"); }

I am not sure what your "click" function is. Maybe it isn't declared yet or something. Or what is happening is your function is named click "function click(){...}" which instead needs to be click = function(){...}

Comment: I left the `click` function out for simplicity, but yes, it is defined.One thing that really stumps me is how in the HTML, you can define it as `"click(this);"`, where you give it a function and can pass a variable. The only way I can think this could be replicated in JS would be to also use quotations, since passing the actual function (`b.onclick=click;`) would make it impossible to pass that variable, and trying to do this: `b.onclick=click(this);` would run the function there and give the `onclick` attribute the return value of the function.

Comment: PS, declaring the function right there would be the same as doing `b.onClick=click;`. Which is where the other points came from.

Answer (score 0):

---

```js
(function(){

  // create the button
  var buttonB = document.createElement('button');
  buttonB.id = 'buttonB';
  var textB = document.createTextNode('Button B');
  buttonB.appendChild( textB );
  
  // set the click event on the button
  buttonB.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // console.log('test');
    // console.log( this );
    clickFunc( this );
  });
  
  // populate the DOM-body with the button
  document.body.appendChild( buttonB );

})();

function clickFunc( that ){
  console.log( that );
}
```